# How to escape chars in UserAttributes at AWS Cognito cli

Tags: command-line-interface, amazon-cognito

I need to change value in custom name that includes {,} characters:

```
"UserAttributes": [
        {
            "Name": "custom:bla-bla",
            "Value": "{\"scope\":{\"test\":\"1111111\"}}"
        }
]
```

Theese looks like object, but string.
When i update attribute:
`aws cognito-idp update-user-attributes --region [REGION] --access-token [TOKEN] --user-attributes Name="custom:bla-bla",Value="{\"scope\":{\"test\":\"222222\"}}"`
i have:

```
Error parsing parameter '--user-attributes': Expected: '=', received: '"' for input:
Name=name2,Value={"scope":{"test":"222222"}}
                  ^
```

I try escape curly brackets:
`Value="\{\"scope\":\{\"test\":\"222222\"\}\}"`
but nothing:

```
Error parsing parameter '--user-attributes': Expected: ',', received: '"' for input:
Name=name2,Value=\{"scope":\{"test":"222222"\}\}
                   ^
```

When I did what сli wanted me to do:
`Value="{scope={test=222222}}"`
i have:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter UserAttributes[0].Value, value: {'scope': {'test': '222222'}}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

I know that valid type is string, but i couldn't input string.
Can anyone help me?